# Python Pandas Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file with four columns: `Category`, `Type`, `Provider`, and `Cost`.

```
Category ,Type,Provider,Cost 
Home,Mortgage,Real Homes,"$1,500.00"
Utilities,Gas,Landsberg Gas,$100.00
Utilities,Electric,Edison,$100.00
Utilities,Internet,Verizon Fios,$60.00
Food,Groceries,Ralphs,$280.00
```

I imported the csv file into a DataFrame using the following code:

```
bills = pd.read_csv('Bills.csv')
```

I then tried to read the column names in the terminal, e.g., `bills.Category`.

I found that `bills.Category` and `bills.Cost` could not be read and returned attribute errors. I modified the CSV file so that `Category` became `mainCategory` and `Cost` became `Price`. After revising, I re-ran the method above and the columns were read and printed correctly to the terminal.

I could not figure out why I was receiving these errors the first time, other than there being some keywords that are restricted in Python/Pandas.

Any explanation of this would be really helpful!

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: Example posted!

Comment: Nice. Will you please also add your CSV file?

Comment: I cant add a file without hosting it. Ive added the csv exactly how it appears in a text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV file has spaces around some of the column names, which is why you are having errors. Right after you call `pd.read_csv`, add this line:

```
bills.columns = bills.columns.str.strip()
```

Then you should be able to do `bills.Category` etc. (if you change `mainCategory` back to `Category`).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'm not sure why the file exported with extra spaces (don't think I put them in myself) but will use this method when this happens again

Comment: Yeah, it happens sometimes. It might be because there are spaces in the Excel spreadsheet? Anyway, remember to accept this answer as soon as you can :)